# Fazer doce ou fazer um doce?

Tags: significado

Eu perguntei a minha mãe se ela ia fazer a batata doce para comer, ao que ela me respondeu "vou fazer doce". Eu perguntei-lhe "vais fazer um doce com a batata doce?" e ela respondeu me "Não vou fazer um doce, vou fazer doce", o que me deixou confusa e acabamos por entrar numa discussão sobre qual das frases estaria correta. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Já agora, se soubéssemos exatamente o que é que a mãe fez com a batata doce, poderíamos ver melhor qual das frases é mais apropriada.

Answer (score 7):

As duas frases são gramaticais, mas têm significados algo diferentes.

*Vou fazer **um doce**.* *Doce* aqui é um substantivo contável, e poderia designar por exemplo um pudim de batata doce, servido num prato ou numa taça, para ser comido ao jantar. Poderíamos também dizer "esta batata doce é demasiada para um doce só; vou fazer dois, comemos um hoje, e o outro fica para amanhã." Do mesmo modo, poderíamos dizer "vou fazer duas tortas."

*Vou fazer **doce**.* *Doce* aqui é usado como substantivo não contável, e designa a substância, que pode ser pesada ou medida em litros, mas não contada. *Doce* neste sentido, pelo menos em Portugal, seria uma espécie de geleia, compota ou em geral um doce de comer à colher (por oposição a um bolo ou torta que se corta à fatia). Do mesmo modo diríamos "vou fazer geleia" ou vou "fazer compota."

Nalguns casos, as duas frases poderão ser apropriadas. Suponhamos que eu tenciono fazer uma compota ou uma coisa com o aspeto de compota numa taça grande para ser servida como sobremesa, e me perguntam, "Que vais fazer com essa batata doce?" Eu posso responder, "Vou fazer um doce," referindo-me à taça com o doce, ou "Vou fazer doce," referindo-me à substância.

Answer (score 3):

**No Brasil, usam-se as duas formas**, talvez com uma diferença muito sutil. Eu entenderia a frase sem o artigo indefinido da seguinte forma:

Certos doces são conhecidos em todo o território nacional: doce de banana, doce de batata, doce de abóbora, etc. A receita é quase sempre a mesma, todos sabem como é feito, e geralmente não usamos o artigo.

- "Vou fazer doce de batata" disse a mãe ao filho.
- "Nós temos doce de abóbora e de banana", disse o garçom. "Eu vou querer doce de abóbora" respondeu a moça.  Mas ela também poderia ter dito "eu vou querer o doce de abóbora". Em outra situação o garçom poderia ter dito "nós temos um doce de banana feito com bananas e leite condensado". Neste caso seria uma receita diferente desse doce

**Acho - e isso é minha impressão pessoal - que o artigo é omitido quando o tipo de doce é muito comum em  nosso cardápio e todos conhecem o seu sabor e sabem como é feito.**  Para doces de frutas exóticas, ou se a receita foge aos padrões habituais ou não sabemos como foi feito, talvez o artigo indefinido seja mais usado:

- "Comprei um doce de banana."  (não sei como foi feito)
- "Ela disse que vai fazer um doce de Kiwi."
- "A Maria faz um doce de banana que é maravilhoso" (é diferente dos habituais)

Comment: Não me lembrei desta, mas tudo isto é válido em Portugal também. A minha fasquia para deixar cair o artigo é capaz de ser mais baixa que a tua. Como _doce_ em Portugal pode ser sinónimo de compota (não sei se é no Brasil), posso dizer _comprei doce de banana_ sem saber exatamente como ele é, se tem raspa de laranja ou canela ou gengibre ou o que seja. Toda a gente entenderia.

Comment: A lógica continua a ser a distinção entre contáveis e não contáveis. Na tua resposta usamos artigo para nos referirmos a um tipo de doce distinto de outros da mesma classe (contamos tipos de doce), na minha para nos referirmos a uma unidade física (que implicitamente admite a possibilidade de várias unidades que podem ser contadas).

Comment: O que são frutas exóticas no Brasil? Laranja?!? (Será que seria uma boa pergunta para abrir...?)

Comment: @ANeves     Não seria uma pergunta sobre língua portuguesa. Frutas exóticas são aquelas que não são produzidas em um determinado país ou região e são importadas.  Nosso solo e clima não são adequados à cultura de kiwis, peras, cerejas, blueberries, cramberries, etc. que são, então, consideradas frutas exóticas.

Answer (score 2):

No Brasil, as duas frases estão corretas e não há muita diferença. Geralmente, o artigo dá ênfase para um doce mais especial. Porém, nem sempre esta regra vale, usando-se as duas formas para qualquer doce.

Agora, há uma curiosidade: no Brasil, "fazer doce" e "fazer um doce" também são expressões idiomáticas. Que significam mostrar falta de vontade em fazer ou aceitar algo, mais precisamente, se refere  ao tempo da contrariedade entre fazer e aceitar algo.

- Exemplo 1: Pedi para Maria arrumar o quarto e ela fez doce até começar a tarefa.
- Exemplo 2: Comprei chocolate Nestlé para Zeca. Ao receber ele fez um doce para comer, pois ele queria um chocolate de outra marca.